# webpy, how to extra add data to a form?

Tags: python, forms, web.py

i need a form with "records" generated from the db.

For each DB record, in addition to form fields, it need to contain also images & record description, e.g.

```
<tr> <td> rec 15, <img src=fnamex.jpg>, <input name=inp15> <checkbox name=chk15> </td> </tr>
```

so i'm confused about the how, when & where to create the form:

1. should the form generation method occur in my "model.py" ? in the template ?
2. how do I keep all the element of a "record" together for later iteration in the template ?
3. where should i add the "extra" data (e.g. image source & title) ? to the form object? in a paralel object list?

Comment: i ended up writing the form & extra-data directly in the template, and my own form validation & handling, but i'm curious to know what's the intended way in webpy.

Answer (score 0):

To add elements to a Web.py form function, you can do this:

```
    args = ()
    for a in range(0,2):
        args = args + (web.form.Textbox(a), ) # Forces tuple type
    tmp = web.form.Form(*args)
```