# Webpy form add checkbox for each line - align form elements horizontal

Tags: python, web.py

I have a matrix of elements such as:

```
column_1 column_2 column_3
val_1_1  val_1_2  val_1_3   <checkbox>
val_2_1  val_2_2  val_2_3   <checkbox>
Submit
```

I have the data from Column_{1,2,3} and need to add the checkbox for each line.

How can I render such a form? I tried to use [webpy, how to extra add data to a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483154/webpy-how-to-extra-add-data-to-a-form)
which was helpful but the problem is that when adding a new element to the Form it is added bellow.

Additional question: how can elements of a form can be aligned horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best solution and which I will try to use is found here:
 http://webpy.org/cookbook/form_fields

LaterEdit:
 Solve it by overriding the render method from web.form.Form